# In SpringBoot, what is the correct way in annotating fields with default value

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mysql-workbench, spring-boot-test

I am new with Spring Boot. I am trying to create an application using Spring Tool Suite with Mysql Workbench that uses JPA, MysqlConnectorJ as dependencies.

I have an Entity called "CredentialType"

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name = "mactyp")
public class CredentialType {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="credential_type_id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="credential_type_name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="date_added")
    private LocalDateTime dateAdded;
    @Column(name="date_modified")
    private Date dateLastModified;
    @Column(name="is_active")
    private boolean isActive;

    ...getters() and setters()...
}
```

Table definition below (Script generated by Mysql Workbench)

```
CREATE TABLE `mactyp` (
  `credential_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `credential_type_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`credential_type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

`date_added` column default value is `current_timestamp`

However, when I try to run the test below,

```
@Test
public void testCreateCredentialType() {
    //DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    //LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    //System.out.println(dtf.format(now));

    CredentialType credentialType = new CredentialType();
    credentialType.setName("Application");
    //credentialType.setDateAdded(now);

    credentialTypeRepository.save(credentialType);
}
```

it returns

```
2020-04-26 01:09:23.962  WARN 8352 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
2020-04-26 01:09:23.962 ERROR 8352 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'date_added' cannot be null
```

I was expecting it would have automatically insert the datetime / timestamp in Mysql. I don't know why I get the error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Adding insertable = false will remove the column being added in the insert script generated by hibernate (but will be available for select) and database default value will be used.

```
 @Column(name="date_added", insertable = false)
 private LocalDateTime dateAdded;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
`date_added` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
```

DEFAULT does not guard against `null`. In plain SQL, if you set `date_added = null`, the column will be null and hence the error will be thrown.

Default Value only works in cases where you do something like `insert into mactype(credential_type_id, credential_type_name) values (.., ..)` and do not specify the column for which you have specified default value.

In your case, you can leverage `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` annotated methods in your entity class.

Answer (score 0):

When data inserted in the database `date_added` value is `null`.
Means insert query executed like

```
insert into mactyp(.., date_added,...) values (..,null, ..)
```

So, by this query you are trying to set null value on not null field.
That's why error says

```
Column 'date_added' cannot be null
```

The mysql default value will be applied when you don't try to insert a column using query.

Use `@CreationTimestamp` on the column to set the current timestamp in the query.

```
@CreationTimestamp
private LocalDateTime dateAdded;
```

Find more details [here](https://thoughts-on-java.org/persist-creation-update-timestamps-hibernate/)

Answer (score 0):

For `Date` fields you can use the annotations below:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@CreationTimestamp
@Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
private Date createdAt;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@UpdateTimestamp
@Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = true)
private Date updatedAt;
```